# c# mvc only one user to edit tree view at one time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Today, i have a tree view for users to edit it, but i want to lock the action to prevent that A user submit the edited node after B user already deleted the A user's edit node;

I have searched the approach about this scenario, and i prefer to do it at the action filter, if one user gets in this page then set a flag to record, and after the user leaves this page, release the flag;

But i needs help about: 
(1)how to set the flag when user entering the page by action filter,
(2)how to catch the correct timing when user leaves the page and inform the   action filter to remove the tag by javascript or razor helper,
(3)during the locked period, throw what exception to the other user on the page?

Comment: You probably want to use websockets (maybe SignalR) to keep UI in sync between all clients.

Comment: thanks for this info, SignalR may probably what i need, i will do the research about it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do something like this (I am testing my skills to add meaningful comment rather than describing the code :))

```
public EditTree()
{
    // Get current logged in user, check if user has permission

    lock(_treeLock)
    {
        // Check if tree can be edited at this moment
        if(!isTreeEditable())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

            //Or

            return Json("ERROR"); // Display an error on the client as you wish.
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the flag in DB so then no one else can edit

            // Return the tree data for edition
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to allow user to edit the tree or view the changes in real time, making that possible involves handling a lot many cases (broken connection, DB failure, etc). I suggest you carefully review your requirement and design for simplicity.

To sync the tree for all user in real time you need to use a persistent connection between server and all clients (use SignalR).

Comment: thanks for sharing, but i have locked the file if more than one operation come in, they will do sequentially; and now i want prevent the situation about A user seen the node which was deleted by B user, any ideas about this?

Comment: So you want to allow multiple user editing the tree at the same time i.e. one user modifies in one browser, all other user should see that change in real time?

Comment: yes, i hope it could be achieved, is it possible according to my logic? or anything needs to take into consideration?

Comment: Well yes, making that possible involves handling a lot many cases (broken connection, DB failure, etc). I suggest you carefully review your requirement and design for simplicity. To sync the tree for all user in real time you need use a persistent connection between server and all clients (use SignalR).

Comment: And what happens if the user goes of to lunch and gets hit by a bus (; The flag never gets reset and no one else can edit it. You should implement [concurrency control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189132%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), for example using a `TimeStamp` field so user A is informed if user B has changed the data

Comment: Absolutely @StephenMuecke there are many such cases to be thought of and handled gracefully.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thanks for info, so how about not setting the flag, and just to sync & refresh the page for all users in this page?

Comment: @SBirthare and what do you think about this thought? if i remove the flag, and just focus on sync the page, there's always exist time order, right?

Comment: What do you mean by sync the page?

Comment: using the SignalR, if caller edit the page, then others will receieve the info to refresh the page.

Comment: Force refresh or optional? If optional, what if they ignored? Yes timing will cause conflicts. Sorry I am asking more questions than answering. But it will help you prepare and handle possible cases.

Comment: i prefer to force, cuz of the editing the same tree, the slower one will be refreshed, then i only have to deal with the missing info on the page, i think

Comment: @JimNeo, That may help, but a 'sync' wont be instantaneous. You will still need other mechanisms so if user A deletes an item and a millisecond later user B tries to open it, you need to inform then.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke so that would be something like custom exception to handle the instantaneous situation, or any good idea?

Comment: @JimNeo, I don't think it needs to be an exception, just return the new view with a message to the user.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke just like the above said, force refreshing & alert(or dialog), right?

Comment: @JimNeo, Which ever way works best for you :) Main thing is that you don't rely on just trying to sync the views